# Using same session ID in ajax can't connect to MySQL DB

Tags: php, session, mysql-connect

I have made a generic PHP script to use for an AJAX call.  I have the username and password for the mysql connection stored in SESSION variables.  In order to start the same session in this ajax script, I pass the session ID via post to the ajax script.  The variables are being passed correctly and I checked using `error_log` that the username and password SESSION variables are the correct values.  Here is the ajax_script.php:

```
<?php

session_id($_POST['session_id']);
session_start();

mysql_connect('10.X.X.X',$_SESSION['username'],$_SESSION['password']);

$results = mysql_query($_POST['query']);

echo json_encode($results);

?>
```

However, the connection cannot be established.  I checked the log file and this is the error:

```
 PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'username'@'25.1.1.1' (using password: YES) in /ajax_script.php on line 6, referer: http://25.1.1.1/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=180
```

Does anyone know why I cannot connect like this?

Previously I made a similar script, but did NOT start the same session referencing the session_id like above.  I passed user names and passwords via post, and the connection worked.

Thanks!

** EDIT ** Sorry, I used the wrong IP for the mysql connection.  the following code works:

```
<?php

session_start();

$ajax_connection = mysql_connect('10.X.X.X',$_SESSION['username'],$_SESSION['password']);

$result_set = array();

while ($result_set[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
    // do nothing
}

echo json_encode($results);

?>
```

Comment: show user data from users table maybe you forget set hostname or set to localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to

```
session_id($_POST['session_id']);
```

Just `session_start()` is enough

Maybe your session is expiring on close. Use the following snippet on both pages

```
session_cache_expire(30); //expire in 30 minutes
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/295264) answer for more information on session expiring.

Comment: i see that i don't need to use session_id(), thanks.  But the connection still does not work.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind, may be the session is expire on page close

Comment: thanks yes i just realized i was using wrong IP for the connection... :-/